# Regex - Extract number from a link

Tags: regex

I have this link `www.xxx.yy/yyy/zzzzzz/xyz-z-yzy-/93797038` and I want to take the number `93797038` in order to pass it into another link.

For example: I want afterwards something like `www.m.xxx.yy/93797038` which is the same page as before but in its mobile version.

In general, I know that I have to type `www.xxx.yy/(.*)` for extracting anything following the in the main url and then I group the result with `www.m.xxx.yy/%1` which redirects to the same page but in the mobile version.

Any ideas how to do it?

***EDIT**:* The link `www.xxx.yy/yyy/zzzzzz/xyz-z-yzy-/93797038` is automated. The part that is the same each time is only the `www.xxx.yy` . Every time the system runs produces different urls. I want each time to take the number from those urls, e.g. the `93797038` in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\/(\d+?)$` will get the trailing digits after the final `/`.

[image]

Comment: What's the URL of the site that visualizes regexes like this?

Comment: I don't want javascript-style regular expression but the general notation of regexp

Comment: @kokosg I don't know what you mean. You don't specify a language and this regular expression works in just about every language that supports them.

Comment: @kokosg Sorry, I still don't understand what you are asking for. You only tagged your question with "regex" so regular expression help is all I can give you. With this regular expression you can get the number you are looking for.

Comment: So the regex will be www.xxx.yy/\/(\d+?)$ to give me back the number? What am I missing here?

Comment: @kokosg Apply the regular expression `\/(\d+?)$` to your string. The first submatch is your number.

Comment: @DavidPärsson It's not needed in this regex because you can be greedy in this case. I just prefer using the non-greedy idiom `+?` in general.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want regex? You can use

```
string str = @"www.xxx.yy/yyy/zzzzzz/xyz-z-yzy-/93797038";
string digit = str.Split('/').Last();
```

instead.